# How to run a timeout "within" a script?

Tags: scripts, timeout

I have a script which contains several commands, and one of them takes a bit of time. The script normally reads a list.txt file, and runs the commands on each row. The problem is some rows take a lot of time, so I want the script to get stopped if it takes for example 3 minutes, and go to the next line. What solution do you propose? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `timeout` command . Just place it before the command you want to run and add time limit. For example:

```
timeout 3 find  /
```

From `info timeout` documentation:

```
‘timeout’ runs the given COMMAND and kills it if it is still running
after the specified time interval.  Synopsis:

     timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...

   COMMAND must not be a special built-in utility (*note Special
built-in utilities::).
```

Comment: Always welcome. Please consider clicking the check-mark to accept this post as accepted solution.